# Azure Data Studio data script for indexes

Tags: ddl, azure-data-studio

I can't access the option "Scrip as Create" for indexes using Azure Data Studio. I just have the refresh option [image]

I think that should be like that, no?

[image]

I've searched on Internet some solution, but I didn't found anything. Someone could help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `script as create` option for index. The solution is to click on `script as create` over the table. It will generate the creation script of the table along with the indexes and constraints.